# laravel 5.4 Как организовать хранение значений зависимых полей

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица продуктов, есть таблица свойств для продуктов (для каждого продукта могут использоваться разные свойства). Организованно это все через связь многие-ко-многим. Получается что есть продукт (например пивасик) и есть его свойства (например цвет - темный, крепость - 4,5 и т.д.). Вопрос, как хранить вот эти значения? Думаю, что в той же таблице связей(pivot), добавить в неё кроме id-шек ещё и value, но как тянуть эти value?
Код
Product

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\ProductFields',
            'product_field_relationships',
            'product_id',
            'product_field_id'
        );
    }
}
```

ProductFields

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductFields extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'type'
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Product',
            'product_field_relationships',
            'product_field_id',
            'product_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Миграция для таблицы связей

```
SSchema::create('product_field_relationships', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_field_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('value');
    });

    Schema::table('product_field_relationships', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('product_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('products')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('product_field_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('product_fields')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
   $products = Product::all();
   return view('products.index', [
       'products' => $products
   ]);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->description }}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach($product->fields as $field)
            {{ $field->pivot }}
        @endforeach
    </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

`{{ $field->pivot }}` к сожалению не содержит поля `value`. Как вариант постоянно доставать его ещё дополнительным запросом  - но это не верное решение, думаю есть способ проще. Прошу помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно по сути вы сделали, упустили только одно, нужно было указать что в `pivot` хранится поле `value` в `Product`:

```
public function fields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\ProductFields',
            'product_field_relationships',
            'product_id',
            'product_field_id'
        )->withPivot('value');
    }
```

И аналогично в реляции `Fields`:

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Product',
            'product_field_relationships',
            'product_field_id',
            'product_id'
        )->withPivot('value');
    }
```

И теперь вы сможете получить значение обращаясь вот так:

```
$field->pivot->value
```

Добавлять же значения вот так:

```
$product->fields()->attach(1, ['value' => 'Значение']);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)) Все прекрасно отработало!

Comment: @OlegShleif замечательно)